# Connecting to a SQLLite db with SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, sqlbulkcopy

I'm writing a unit test in c# for a function that is responsible for using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy to copy a DataTable to a database server.

I use SQLLite for unit tests, and wanted to connect to my SQLLite in memory database with SqlBulkCopy, and then bulk copy that test data into the SQLLite db.

However, I can't seem to get the connection string right.

I originally tried

```
var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy("FullUri=file::memory:?cache=shared")
```

Then

```
var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=:memory:;Cache=Shared")
```

Which didn't recognize `Cache`
So then I tried

```
var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=:memory:")
```

out of desperation, which simply timed out when attempting to connect to the database.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish here possible?  If it is, can someone please help me with the connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this was that you cannot connect SqlBulkCopy to a SQLite instance.

What I did to solve my problem (unit test a part of the code that used SqlBulkCopy) was to create a wrapper around SqlBulkCopy that is implemented using SqlBulkCopy for production code, and with a mock bulk copy in test code.  Effectively decoupling the dependency on SqlBulkCopy itself.

Specifically, I created

```
public interface IBulkCopy : IDisposable {
    string DestinationTableName { get; set; }
    void CreateColumnMapping(string from, string to);
    Task WriteToServerAsync(DataTable dt);
}
```

Then, I implemented this as

```
public class SQLBulkCopy : IBulkCopy { 

    private SqlBulkCopy _sbc;

    public string DestinationTableName {
        get { return _sbc.DestinationTableName; }
        set { _sbc.DestinationTableName = value; }
    }

    public SQLBulkCopy(IDBContext ctx) { 
        _sbc = new SqlBulkCopy((SqlConnection)ctx.GetConnection());
    }

    public void CreateColumnMapping(string from, string to) {
        _sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(from, to));
    }

    public Task WriteToServerAsync(DataTable dt) {
        return _sbc.WriteToServerAsync(dt);
    }

}
```

And in my test utilities I mocked out "bulk copy" with just inserts:

```
class MockBulkCopy : IBulkCopy {

    private IDBContext _context;

    public MockBulkCopyHelper(IDBContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string DestinationTableName { get; set; }

    public void CreateColumnMapping(string fromName, string toName) {
        //We don't need a column mapping for raw SQL Insert statements.
        return;
    }

    public virtual Task WriteToServerAsync(DataTable dt) {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            using (var cn = _context.GetConnection()) {
                using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand()) {
                    cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO {DestinationTableName}({GetCsvColumnList(dt)}) VALUES {GetCsvValueList(dt)}";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Where `GetCsvColumnList` and `GetCsvValueList` I implemented as helper functions.

Comment: So what did you actually test here? I believe it only tests if all the column mappings are done properly. If that's the case, you could've extracted that functionality into a separate class and wrote unit tests for that and leave your bulk copy operations class alone. It would've been easier, IMO.

Comment: Yes that's a good point.  This wasn't test driven development, and the idea here was just to get some unit tests written without modifying the code that it's testing for the sake of deadlines.  Ideally I would have gone the route you suggest, but the code I was working with was tightly coupled to sbc, so I had to do this workaround mock.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `SqlBulkCopy` for SQLite. `SqlBulkCopy` has been done for SQL Server.

Normally the trick to dramatically improve performance for SQLite is making sure a transaction is used.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [.NET Bulk Operations](http://bulk-operations.net/)

This library is not free but allows you to easily perform and customize all bulk operations:

- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

Example

```
// Easy to use
var bulk = new BulkOperation(connection);
bulk.BulkInsert(dt);
bulk.BulkUpdate(dt);
bulk.BulkDelete(dt);
bulk.BulkMerge(dt);

// Easy to customize
var bulk = new BulkOperation<Customer>(connection);
bulk.BatchSize = 1000;
bulk.ColumnInputExpression = c => new { c.Name,  c.FirstName };
bulk.ColumnOutputExpression = c => c.CustomerID;
bulk.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = c => c.Code;
bulk.BulkMerge(customers);
```

**EDIT:** Answer comment

> I want to load a data table from SQLite then "bulk copy" it in other databases

This situation is possible but requires 2 connection

```
DbConnection sourceConnection = // connection from the source
DbConnection destinationConnection = // connection from the destination

// Fill the DataTable using the sourceConnection
dt = ...;

// BulkInsert using the destinationConnection
var bulk = new BulkOperation(destinationConnection);
bulk.BulkInsert(dt);
```

Comment: I want to load a data table from SQLite then "bulk copy" it in other databases (MySQL, Oracle, Postgre and SQL Server). I think it is possible with BulkOperation but a code sample would help a lot

Comment: I have tried the Z.BulkOperations NuGet package to insert 100,000 simple records (Id INTEGER, Name TEXT) into a SQLite database.
On my machine using BulkOperation.BulkInsert (DataTable or Entities) is about 2 times slower than manually inserting the records via a SQLiteCommand.

Which is too bad, since I was hoping for some solution that would allow me to bulk insert records into a SQLite database faster than with a SQLiteCommand.

Comment: Hello David, if you can provide a runnable solution here: info@zzzprojects.com, we will be happy to look at it and find out why this is slower in your case.